# Tracing stolen android tablet via MAC address

Tags: network-scanners, mac-address

I lost my tablet , but I can see that the tablet is connected to the network on my router: [image]:So I know the MAC address but I am unable to trace my tablet using this information and I am running out of time before the battery drains. I suspect it is stolen but at some distance as the signal quality shown is 17% while other devices show above 50%, from this I suspect it is either gone deep down something or is far away but still in the network.

So how to track this device XX...BE:FB? I also get the IP adress of the tablet from the router but the PING to that IP does not return any response and is blocking i.e not returning to command prompt.

Update:

Now the signal has reduced to 8% as shown in router, I suspect that the tablet is in standby power saving mode where does not allow much network i\o.

Comment: Would be weird if someone stole your android tablet and just stays connected to your wifi.

Comment: Still possible in a really tough area (building with lots of appartements, campus, etc ...)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/895598/how-to-track-a-android-tablet-in-the-same-network-using-mac-address/895604#895604

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your OS, you could use [NetStumbler](http://www.netstumbler.com/downloads/) (Windows) or [iStumbler](https://istumbler.net/) (Mac OS X).
Those tools allow you to track devices WiFi signals.
Using them on a portable device, you can move around and find in which direction the signal gets stronger, until you find where your tablet is.